# access mikrotik webfig through the private openvpn address

Tags: openvpn, remote, mikrotik

I am using Mikrotik (7.1.1) router with an **ovpn client** interface connected to an **openvpn server** installed on ubuntu ec2. Everything worked fine:

[image: ip/address print command]

I want to use my laptop (connected to the same OpenVPN server) to access remotely to the /WebFig using its private IP (10.8.0.4). I have already added firewall rules to accept incoming TCP requests on port 80 but I don't get any response.

Also from the Mikrotik terminal, I couldn't ping the 10.8.0.1:

`ping -I ovpn-out1 10.8.0.1` return timeout.

[image: ping]

Answer (score 0):

i just switched to PPTP protocol and everything worked fine

Comment: Could you give me more info about how you switched to PPTP?